# Broken ssl, what to do

Tags: ssl

I have a site and i implemented ssl there. but when i browse it, the security seals dont come. i asked to godaddy, they replaid:

> Thank you for contacting online support. I cannot replicate the issue you have described. The error you described is caused by the way your site has been designed. If you receive this error, you have a combination of secure and non-secure objects on the page. For example, if your secure website was https://www.domain.tld and you added an object (an image, script, flash file, etc.) to that page that was located at http://www.domain.tld/image.jpg, you would break the seal.
>
> You will need to change your design to
>   link to objects using https (ie
>   https://www.domain.tld/image.jpg) or
>   modify your site design to use
>   relative paths (/image.jpg).
>
> This error can only be corrected by
>   modifying your site design. Please
>   contact your web designer or the
>   manufacturer of your web design
>   software if you require additional
>   assistance modifying your site design.

but the problem is i made everything,all my images javascripts are unders https, but the seal still not coming, saying: some content insecure. what is the problem.

Comment: You have a 404 for https://lendersutopia.com/css/jsTabs

Comment: No, that isn't.  However, you should fix it anyway.  You probably want to add `.css` to the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in line 8 of `jqueryslidemenu.js`:

```
 var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', 'http://lendersutopia.com/images/down.gif', 23], right:['rightarrowclass', 'images/right.gif']}
```

You should change it to

```
 var arrowimages={down:['downarrowclass', 'images/down.gif', 23], right:['rightarrowclass', 'images/right.gif']}
```